# Can't create new events from template after upgrade to 5.9

Tags: civievent, templates

I recently upgraded to CiviCRM 5.9, WordPress 5.0.3 and PHP 7.2. Now when I try to create a new event from a template, after clicking 'continue' the template is cloned and I'm thrown into a template editing page. The new event is never created.

This happens both with pre-existing templates and with a completely new template. It does not happen with new events created without a template.

It is essentially the inverse of [this bug that was patched last February](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21743) - not sure if this is an unintended side-effect, or if I've set something up weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is indeed a bug: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/653

Answer (score 2):

This is a regression bug and is logged [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/653). I have submitted a [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13478) for it which should get merge this week and will be available in next release. In meantime can you please QA if it fixes the bug by applying patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13478.patch)?

Please post your QA results on [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13478) so that it will help to speed up the process in getting the PR merged ASAP.

Thanks

Pradeep